# What does fork() returns to its parent when it is called in a child process of another process?

Tags: fork

I guess it should not be zero.

EDIT: It is zero.

Comment: Fork will *always* return `-1` (on error), `0` (in the child process) or a positive number (in the parent process). And the parent process is always the process which does the "forking". If it's a child of another process doesn't matter, if the child process calls `fork` to create a new process, then the child process is *also* a parent process.

Comment: [This `fork` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) might be a good read.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The PID of the child process is returned in the parent and 0 in the child upon success and -1 upon failure

Answer (score 0):

A Fork() call always returns pid(process id) of the created child to its parent.
pid_t fork(void);